# Create indices for a 2D Tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to do something like this:

Suppose the input Tensor is a `(2, 3)` Tensor with the value like:

```
[[1 2]
 [3 4]
 [5 6]]
```

I am flattening the 2D Tensor into 1D by doing:

```
input = tf.reshape(input, [-1])
```

So the input now becomes `[1 2 3 4 5 6]`.

But I also create a 1D Tensor that indexes the previous Tensor, so the desired output is `[0 0 1 1 2 2]`. How should I create this Tensor in TF?

In general, if the input Tensor has a shape of `(X, Y)`. I would like to create a 1D Tensor that looks like:

```
[0 0 0 ... 0 1 ....1 2 ... 2 ... X-1 ... X-1]
```

where each value is repeated Y - 1 times.

Comment: It seems the desired output of your example only represents the row indices. Do you also need the column indices?

Comment: @SaulloCastro - I don't need the column indices. I've also updated the question to reflect this. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it; What this does is first create a single row indices and then repeat each indice by the number of columns the original tensor has using `tf.tile`; reshaping the 2d indices back gives what you need.

```
t = tf.constant([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])

X, Y = t.shape
idx = tf.range(X.value)
idx_2d = tf.reshape(idx, [-1,1])
idx_2d_full = tf.tile(idx_2d, [1, Y.value])
idx_flat = tf.reshape(idx_2d_full, [-1])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(idx_flat))

[0 0 1 1 2 2]
```

Comment: Thanks! I made a mistake and thought `tf.tile` only accepts a scalar value for the multiplies argument so I originally implemented something like: create a 1D Tensor that looks like `[0 1 2 3 4 5]` and then divide it by 3. :) Your implementation is definitely cleaner.